# Difference of random numbers generation in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am a newbie in python. I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm, which I have previously implemented in MatLab. I need to create several chromosomes (individuals) for my initial population. In MatLab, I used to do this with a `rand` function and It used to give me plenty of unique (or at least different enough) initial population. But Here in python, I have tried different methods of `random` but among 50 individuals I have only 3 to 4 unique chromosomes. Here this is my python code in  `__main__.py` :

```
for i in range(pop_size):
        popSpace.append(Chromosom(G=mG,M=mM))
        sum_Q+=popSpace[i].Q
```

And my `Chromosom` class:

```
class Chromosom:   
    def __init__(self,G,M):
            self.Q = 0
            self.V = []
            self.Chr = [0]*len(self.M)
            self.M= M
            self.G= G
            self.randomChromosom() 
            self.updateQ_Qs() 

    def randomChromosom(self):
        for m in range(len(self.M)):
            if (random.random()< 0.5):
                self.Chr[m] = 1
            else:
                self.Chr[m] = 0
```

I have also tried to get random bits but results still were the same. For example, I have used `print(str(main.mRand.getrandbits(6))` to see the results in the console and realized that there were too much-duplicated numbers. Is there a method to create more unique random numbers? in MatLab, the same code with `rand` function was working well (of course pretty slowly). Having such a close initial population causes poor results in the next steps (also I should mention that the randomness problem causes similar mutations too).  My problem is that there are so many similar chromosomes. For example, I have several `01111001`s which is strange considering their probability of occurrence.

Comment: A "more unique" random number is then no more random. Can you also define the function `updateQ_Qs()`, what is `M` and what is `G` ? Also python do not work like matlab, you cannot assign `Chr[m]` if `Chr` is empty since `Chr[m]` does not exist. This code should return an error.  Provide a working  example and give us the expected result.

Comment: `updateQ_Qs()` is my fitness function that returns a float value for each chromosome. Saying "more unique" I wanted to mention that for example, I have several chromosomes with `01111001` gene order which is strange (I have edited the code).

Comment: The probability to have at least two identical series (of length 8) among 50 series is `1-prod(1-[(0:49)/2^8])` = 99.41% so this is not really surprising

Comment: `numpy.random.randint(0, 2, 8)`

Comment: 8 bits → 0÷255<365 - Birthday paradox in the offing.

Comment: I have tried `NumPy` but the results didn't change.

Comment: Why would you say that its probability is `1-prod(1-[(0:49)/2^8])`? I thought the probability of selecting the same individual k times over 50 independent iterations should be `length(combntns([1:50],k))*1/256^k`.

Comment: You ikely hve other problems in this code. random.random  - and other functions in random is just good enough for these - but the code you've posted here would raise `AttributeError` on trying to get to `self.M`  before assiging it on `__init__`. Otherwise, the code is very litle idiomatic in Python - it is likely you are ending up with the same object holding chromosome data in more than one instance.

Comment: Please, try to elaborate a minimal, complete, example that exhibits  the behaviour you are complaining about - some stand alone script we could just paste here and run. Otherwise, there is no way to help there.

Comment: @Sajjad  As jsbueno said, there is no way the code you wrote could work as written.  And there are a bunch of method attributes that aren't used.  Please provide a minimal example with, say, 100 results.  That being said, this is a really, really, really slow approach.  Using a numpy array of random numbers and calculating everything at once would be much, much faster.